# How does the conductivities of metals and semiconductors vary when placed in the presence of magnetic field?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, metals, hall-effect

Suppose you have two materials one is a metal and other is a heavily doped semiconductor and they are placed in a magnetic field. What experiment will you do to distinguish between them? Does the  conductivity of metals used from Drude's model will remains the same or will it be changed in the presence of magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

One things a magnetic field does is exert a sideways force on a current. This tries to squeeze moving electrons closer together on one side of a wire. This raises their potential energy on one side and reduces it on the other. A difference in energy per electron is a voltage difference. This voltage difference from one side to the other is called the Hall effect.

A conductor would carry a larger current than a semiconductor under the same conditions. It would have a larger Hall voltage.

---

Another thing a magnetic field does is orient spins. Each electron has a quantum mechanical property called spin, even though it doesn't mean the electron is rotating like a classical top. It does mean that an electron is a tiny magnet. If you measure the direction, you find that it can either point up or down, but not in between.

Atoms in a conductor have some electrons that spread out in the material and move around easily. Semi-conductors have fewer such electrons. Both have electrons that stick to the atom and occupy orbitals.

An electron in an orbital orbits around the nucleus, though again it isn't really like the classical situation. Never the less, the electron generates a magnetic field with constraints on its orientation.

Each orbitals has room for an even numbers of electrons When full half are spin up and half spin down. Likewise the orbital magnetic fields from the electrons in a full orbital cancel. A magnetic field only has a small effect on these. But some orbitals are partially filled and have electrons where the fields don't cancel. These atoms are magnetic.

The field can try to orient them, but sometimes they are hard to turn. In some materials, neighboring atoms line up so that unpaired spins point in opposite directions, like you would expect bar magnets to do. These materials are called anti-ferromagnetic.

In other materials such as iron, the separation is just right that it becomes energetically favorable for the spins to line up parallel. These are called ferromagnets (ferro means iron). Stick-to-the-refrigerator magnets are ferrormagnets.

Some ferromagnets are ceramics, which is a chemical term meaning metal oxide. A metal atom forms a bond with oxygen, and oxygen also forms a bond with the next metal atom. The metal and oxygen each have unpaired spins with orient in opposite directions. That makes all the atoms orient one way, and all the oxygen orient the other. If the metal has a stronger field than oxygen, the net effect is a ferromagnet.

They are many such magnetic effects - paramagnetism, diamagnetism, and others.

An external magnetic field would try to flip these spins. This is why ferromagnets are oriented by a magnetic field. In this, the atoms in orbitals matter. The free conduction electrons do not. So it doesn't matter whether the material is a conductor or semiconductor.

See [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM), where Veritasium and MinutePhysics team up to explain ferromagnets in more detail.

Comment: will the conductivity of metals be the same as given by drude theory or not?